# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (/static/js/26.3ac4f9fa.chunk.js at line 1:1)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chunks

I have been battling with this error for a while and I could not find any solution even though there is many documentation on internet, I use ReactJS. In my scenario, this error triggers every time I do a navigation to another route (history.push), by console logging I detected that it does pass my auth in order to go to the next page, but when trying to pull the javascript chunck from next page it encounters something is not the javascript, It never reached the next page (It does not show up a console log in the useEffect on rendering). I have tried to add the code below into my index.html but it did not work.

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
  <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
  <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

2. I also. tried to disabled the serviceWorker (PWA) but it did not work.

Do you have any other solution, I believe is something related to chuck cache but I do not know how to tackle it anymore, any other ideas?

Thank you very much

Carlos

Comment: Does the error happens during a specific action or user input?

Comment: The action always happen when the user changes page, there's no specific page though. No other action triggers this